# How to verify the client certificate during the tls handshake

Tags: ssl, openssl

I made a tls server by below commands, which will request the client who is connecting to provide a client certificate. And I also simulated a client with the openssl commandline which will provide a client certificate. But it seems that the server didn't check if the client certificate is what exactly we want or not. Do you know how to make the server to do the check?

For the server:

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365 -nodes
openssl s_server -key key.pem -cert cert.pem -accept 44330 -Verify 0
```

For the client:

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout clientkey.pem -out clientcert.pem -days 365 -nodes
openssl s_client -connect 127.0.0.1:44330 -cert clientcert.pem -key clientkey.pem
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... check if the client certificate is what exactly we want or not

You do not specify what you want from the client certificate, that's why it cannot check it. If you want that the client certificate is signed by a specific CA use the `-CAfile` option [as documented](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/s_server.html):

> -CAfile infile
> A file containing trusted certificates to use during client authentication and to use when attempting to build the server certificate chain. The list is also used in the list of acceptable client CAs passed to the client when a certificate is requested.

Thus, if you want to make sure that the client certificate is the self-signed certificate you issued (or some other certificate signed by this), use:

```
 openssl s_server -key key.pem -cert cert.pem -accept 44330 -Verify 0 \
   -CAfile clientcert.pem
```